# String compare is not working as expected in c language

Tags: c, strtok, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main() { 
  char str1[50]="TEST sun raised";
  char str2[4][90]={"sun","in"};
  char delim[] = " ";

  char *ptr=strtok(str1,delim);
  while (ptr!=NULL) {

    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
      if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr)) {
        printf("%s\n",ptr);
        break;
      }
      else {   
      }
    }

    ptr=strtok(NULL,delim);
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Below code should return Test and raised but it returns all strings

Comment: Above Code is not working as expected

Comment: Note: `strcmp(str2[i],ptr)` is true (non-0) when strings differ.  Krishna Reddy CH, is this what you want?

Comment: yes differ string i want but it is not coming

Comment: "Below code should return Test and raised but it returns all strings." I'm sorry but that statement doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

you need to adjust your test `if(-1)` C is true , and `strcmp()` does not return true or false , it return a number positive or negative , and zero if the two strings match, this means that `if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr)` is always true except when str2[i] matches ptr, you can resolve this by using somthing like this to find matches `if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr) == 0)` or  `if(!strcmp(str2[i],ptr))` which return true only if strcmp return 0 ,your test is equivalent to `if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr) != 0)`
 the reason why you can see `sun` in your results is : `sun` does not match with `Test` and `raised` , 
if you are trying to find strings that does not exist only, update your code to this

```
int main()
{
char str1[50]="TEST sun raised";
char str2[4][90]={"sun","in"};
char delim[] = " ";
 char *ptr=strtok(str1,delim);
 while(ptr!=NULL){
   int i=0;
   int found = 0;
   for( i=0;i<4;i++){
   if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr)==0){
         found++;
       break;
   }
}
if(found == 0) printf("%s does not exist \n",ptr);

ptr=strtok(NULL,delim);
}
```

Comment: And the reason why the word "sun" appears to match, when `!=0` means it *wasn't* found, is because one of the *other* strings does not match.

Comment: Consider what happens with `strcmp(str2[2],ptr)`

Comment: Change `if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr))` to `if(strcmp(str2[i],ptr) == 0)` after which your program outputs `sun`.

Comment: are you trying to find matches or if it does not exist ? , the reason why you can see sun when you use `!=0` is because sun match wich sun but does not match with Test and raised => you will see it in the results

Comment: i want the string which doesnt exist in str2 array